# How to test Easypaisa Sandbox API?

Tags: node.js, sandbox, easypaisa

I am trying Easypaisa sandbox API to implement bill payment from this [site](https://sandbox-developer.easypaisa.com.pk/node/28):

```
API:

https://api.eu-de.apiconnect.appdomain.cloud/easypaisaapigw-telenorbankpk-tmbdev/dev-catalog

path: 

POST /GetBillCompanies
```

But it is throwing error:

```
httpCode: '401',
httpMessage: 'Unauthorized',
moreInformation: 'Invalid client id or secret.'
```

Although I am providing a valid client id and secret. I tried this on postman and in the node.js program.